# Парсинг картинок с сайта на С#

Tags: c#

Получаю примерно следующий html код

```
<div class="image layout-left">
<ul class="new-img-border">
<li>
<a href="#" data-spm-anchor-id="0.0.0.0">
<img alt="Original Xiaomi Mi Note Pro 4GB 64GB 5.7" 2K Snapdragon 810 Dual SIM 2560x1440 Android 5.0 Octa Core 13 Million pixels 3010mAh" src="http://g01.a.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1lR0HMXXXXXb8XVXXq6xXFXXXe/Original-Xiaomi-Mi-Note-Pro-4GB-64GB-5-7-2K-Snapdragon-810-Dual-SIM-2560x1440-Android.jpg" style="height: 600px;">
</a>
</li>
<li style="display: none;">
<a href="#">
<img alt="Original Xiaomi Mi Note Pro 4GB 64GB 5.7" 2K Snapdragon 810 Dual SIM 2560x1440 Android 5.0 Octa Core 13 Million pixels 3010mAh" src="http://g01.a.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1K8VPMXXXXXatXFXXq6xXFXXXr/Original-Xiaomi-Mi-Note-Pro-4GB-64GB-5-7-2K-Snapdragon-810-Dual-SIM-2560x1440-Android.jpg" style="height: 600px;">
</a>
</li>
```

Как из этого кода достать и сохранить все картинки на С#?

Comment: Вы пробовали использовать [Aliexpress API](http://portals.aliexpress.com/help/help_center_API.html) вместо того, чтобы парсить html?

Comment: Используй HTTPClient и AngleSharp здессь примеры на C# и 1C http://infostart.ru/public/466196/

Answer (score 1):

Тут необходимо спарсить ссылки, допустим путем перебора строк и поиска в них ключевого слова src= и формируете массив ссылок, далее дергаете следующую функцию.

```
// Sample call : DownLoadFileInBackground2 
public static void DownLoadFileInBackground2 (string address)
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient ();
    Uri uri = new Uri(address);

    // Specify that the DownloadFileCallback method gets called
    // when the download completes.
    client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler (DownloadFileCallback2);
    // Specify a progress notification handler.
    client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(DownloadProgressCallback);
    client.DownloadFileAsync (uri, "pic.jpeg");
}

private void DownloadFileCallback2(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
//что-то делаете после того как файл загрузился
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Используй AngleSharp

```
 var str = @"<div>    <a href = ""#"" data-spm-anchor-id=""0.0.0.0"">
       <img alt = ""Original Xiaomi Mi Note Pro 4GB 64GB 5.7 2K Snapdragon 810 Dual SIM 2560x1440 Android 5.0 Octa Core 13 Million
 pixels 3010mAh""
 src=""http://g01.a.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1lR0HMXXXXXb8XVXXq6xXFXXXe/Original-Xiaomi-Mi-Note-Pro-4GB-64GB-5-7-2K-Snapdragon-810-Dual-SIM-2560x1440-Android.jpg""
 style=""height: 600px;""> </a> </div>";

             var parser = new AngleSharp.Parser.Html.HtmlParser();

             var doc = parser.Parse(str);

 // Получим первую картинку с атрибутами
             var str2 = doc.QuerySelector("a[data-spm-anchor-id]");
             str2 = doc.QuerySelector("a[data-spm-anchor-id]>img[src]"); 
             var addr = str2.Attributes["src"].Value;



 // Получим все    картинки


                     var Картинки = doc.QuerySelectorAll("img[src]");

                     foreach (var стр in Картинки)
                    { var адрес = стр.Attributes["src"].Value; }

  //  Можно применить следующий селектор
    div.image>ul>li>a>img[src]
```